# How do I create a interrupted line in Symbology menu?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I want to create a symbol for my line layer, this should consist of a line, which is interrupted by my symbol. The line should not go through the symbol like in my attached screenshot. How can I do this?

[image: Symbology]

Comment: Most simple method would be to move the symbol on top of the line. But wont work if its transparent.

Comment: You can change symbol layer order using the blue triangles to the right of the window at the top.

Comment: You could add a white box symbol, then have your line layer at the bottom of the draw order so that the box hides it, and your SVG marker is on top of the box.  Or you could create a different SVG marker with the box added.

Comment: Thank you guys!